# Find index in vector where the values start to decrease strictly monotonic

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix

I have bunch of numbers `[a b]` like

```
A = [0    0.001;
     0.01 2    ;
     0.02 0.5  ;
     0.03 0.4  ;
     0.04 0.9  ;
     0.05 0.7  ;
     0.06 0.5  ;
     0.07 0.8  ;
     0.08 0.8  ;
     0.09 0.8  ;
     0.10 0.3  ;
     0.11 0.1  ;
     0.12 0.05 ]
```

I want to find the last value in `b` series which after that `b` value, series decent for example here the answer is `[0.04 0.8]`.
the matrix is really big and I don't need to sort its values.
the matrix form should stay intact.

Comment: whats wrong with `max`?

Comment: Try this - `[~,ind] = max(ab(:,2)); out = ab(ind,:)`

Comment: @Divakar that's what I had in my answer before, that's not what he want...

Comment: @thewaywewalk OP hasn't been clear on this?

Comment: @Divakar not really, I guess he wants to find the index in the second column where all values start to monotonically decrease. Which is not necessarily the maximum value of the whole column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
A = [0    0.001;
     0.01 2    ;
     0.02 0.5  ;
     0.03 0.4  ;
     0.04 0.9  ;
     0.05 0.7  ;
     0.06 0.5  ;
     0.07 0.8  ;
     0.08 0.8  ;
     0.09 0.8  ;
     0.10 0.3  ;
     0.11 0.1  ;
     0.12 0.05 ]

X = find( diff(A(:,2)) > 0 ,1,'last') + 1
out = A(X,:)
```

returns:

```
X =  8
out =  0.0700    0.8000
```

Comment: No. I dont need max. In that case it would be really easy.there is bigger number than 0.8 I didn't write the exact values.It contains 1,1.2,2 ...

Comment: If that is not the answer, than your question is completely unclear to me. Please give a better example.

Comment: Now I think you can get it easily.
the first number which after that every number descending.

Comment: there is a slight problem .
I have 20 data which are equal but it choose the last one.
I need it to choose the first one.

Comment: What do you mean? How is your data arranged? Please edit your question to make it clear.

Comment: i need out=0.07 0.8 but your code gave me out =  0.0900    0.8000

Comment: Everything is working as it should, try `clear A` and `clear X` before you execute it.

Comment: I edited the question.if you run it you will see the answer is [0.09 0.8] but i need [0.07 0.8].